# Menu in RPi Python choice and run two subprocess and kill it

Tags: python-3.x, menu, subprocess

RPi + Python3. I need a menu with 4 options. 
When option 'AA' -> blink_LED33, option 'BB' -> blink_LED35, option 'CC' -> stop_blink _LED33, option 'DD' -> stop_blink_LED35

I need a while loop in blinkLED33.py and blinkLED35.py

**blinkLED33.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
while True:
 GPIO.output(33, GPIO.HIGH)
 print("ON_33.")
 sleep(1)
 GPIO.output(33, GPIO.LOW)
 print("OFF_33.")
 sleep(1)
```

**blinkLED35.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
while True:
 GPIO.output(35, GPIO.HIGH)
 print("ON_35.")
 sleep(1)
 GPIO.output(35, GPIO.LOW)
 print("OFF_33.")
 sleep(1)
```

**menu.py**

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess
import os
(...)

class My_Keyboard:
(...)


if __name__ == "__main__":
(...)

            if clickkey == 'AA':
              #exec(open("blinkLED33.py").read());
              #subprocess.run(["blinkLED33.py"])
              #os.system('python  blinkLED33.py')
              p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'blinkLED33.py'])

            if clickkey == 'BB':
              #exec(open("blinkLED35.py").read());
              #subprocess.run(["blinkLED35.py"])
              #os.system('python  blinkLED35.py')
              p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'blinkLED35.py'])

            if clickkey == 'CC':
            p1.terminate()

            if clickkey == 'DD':
            p2.terminate()

(...)
```

Comment: @Anwarvic the tag "blink" is obsolete because Q OP has nothing to do with "search engine name" Chrome. User HelgeFox was on the ball here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change python for python3.

```
 p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'blinkLED33.py'])

 p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'blinkLED35.py'])
```